# ggplot: rearrange factor order and highlight area by `geom_rect` at the same time

Tags: r, ggplot2

First, the way to specify the order of categorical variables for `ggplot` is to reorder its levels in the `data.frame`. Second, to have an area highlighted on any plot we can use `geom_rect`. Here we need to note that it is a key thing not to pass the data to `geom_rect`, otherwise it does not let us to set `alpha`, thus the gridlines won't be visible. Now there are 2 cases:

- if we pass the data to `geom_rect` (or to the top level `ggplot()`), the order agrees with that in the `data.frame`, but as I mentioned the rectangle won't be transparent
- if we pass the data only to the `geom_point` layer, ggplot rearranges the discrete variables in alphabetical order

How to have both of the two criteria, i.e. have the predefined order and have a transparent rectangle in the desired position?

**Bonus question:** how to have a rectangle at discrete variables with its edges between gridlines, i.e. adjusted by `0.5`? `vjust` and `hjust` are not used arguments here (as a warning tells us). And how to make rectangle filling the whole vertical space (for this we would need to define `ymax` as the `n+1`th factor level, which does not exist).

```
require(ggplot2)

ex <- data.frame(a = factor(letters[1:10]),
                 b = factor(rep(c('b', 'a'), 5)),
                 c = rep(letters[1:5], 2))

ex$a <- factor(ex$a, levels = ex$a[order(ex$b)])

ggplot(
    # uncomment this to see the other failure:
    # ex, aes(y = a, x = c)
) +
    geom_rect(
        aes(
            xmin = 'b',
            xmax = 'd',
            ymin = 'd',
            ymax = 'j'
            ),
        alpha = 0.2
    ) +
    geom_point(
        data = ex,
        aes(
            y = a,
            x = c
        )
    )
```

Comment: Use `data = data.frame()` within `geom_rect()` and `data = ex` within `ggplot()`

Comment: _" how to make rectangle filling the whole vertical space"_ Use `ymax = Inf`.

Comment: Thanks @Axeman, adding `data = data.frame()` indeed makes it possible to have `alpha`. If I leave the `aes(...)` of `geom_point` in `geom_point` it drops the order, if I add it to `ggplot` it says `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'a' not found`. `ymax = Inf` makes good job at the top edge, but `ymin = -Inf` results `Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`.

Comment: Things are easier if you use `annotate(xmin = 'b', xmax = 'd', ymin = 'd', ymax = Inf, geom = 'rect', alpha = 0.2)` instead. But why the ordering is changing I do not know. It might be a bug... If you put the point layer first it does work.

Comment: Thanks @Axeman this works like a charm! I think the reordering issue is not intended, we might call it a bug, but if I put the point layer first, the rectangle will be over the points, changing their colors, right? Anyways, `annotate` is good for this purpose.

Comment: Yes that's correct, the rectangle is now drawn on top of the points (although with an alpha this low the effect is limited).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I can do is to avoid the `data` issue by using `annotate` instead (a data free layer). You somehow need to put `geom_point` first though, but I'm not sure why. It seems like the scale gets determined by the first layer, even though I have supplied the data and mapping already in `ggplot`.

```
ggplot(data = ex, aes(y = a, x = c)) +
    geom_point() +
    annotate(xmin = 'b', xmax = 'd', ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, geom = 'rect', alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]