# Annotate rectangle to start between two factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my example, obtained from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932758/ggplot-rearrange-factor-order-and-highlight-area-by-geom-rect-at-the-same-tim?rq=1):

```
ex <- data.frame(a = factor(letters[1:10]),
                 b = factor(rep(c('b', 'a'), 5)),
                 c = rep(letters[1:5], 2))

ex$a <- factor(ex$a, levels = ex$a[order(ex$b)])
```

When ggploting...

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = ex, aes(y = a, x = c)) +
    geom_point() +
    annotate(xmin = 'b', xmax = 'd', ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, geom = 'rect', alpha = 0.2)
```

... we get this plot:
[image]

However, **how can the gray rectangle start between** `a` **and** `b` **and end between** `d`** and **`e`**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `a` is `1` and `b` is `2`all you have to set is `xmid = 1.5` (ie, between `a` and `b`) and then do the same for `d` and `e`.

```
ggplot(ex, aes(c, a)) +
    geom_point() +
    annotate(xmin = 1.5, xmax = 4.5, 
             ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, 
             geom = "rect", alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]